# Concurrent RDP Sessions Using Multiple VM Instances

Tags: java, javascript, .net, virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I was wondering if anyone has any pointers/resources/examples/advice on whether the following scenario is feasible programmatically:

- Given one computer running Windows or Linux
- Launch multiple VM instances on top of it
- Support an active (sandboxed) RDP connection into each VM instance concurrently
- Have each VM support separate mouse/keyboard input streams so that the simultaneous RDP sessions don't conflict with each other

Is there a way to do this, and have it automated/initiated via some library or language (preferably a C#/C++/Java/Javascript solution if possible)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Yes and Yes.

I run multiple VMs, with multiple concurrent remote desktop connections, all the time.

As far as "automating" the connection, there are many alternatives.  For example, you can simply call "mstsc" in a .bat file.

Comment: Does each RDP connection handle the input events, or do I need to configure them not to clash?